# Javascript: Image error handling & nesting

Tags: javascript

I want an error handling script. If the image is not found, delete(or invisible) the failed loaded  tag. I would appreciate any help!

HTML DOM:

```
<div class="swiper-slide" data-index="2" style="width: 145px; margin-right: 10px;">
    <div class="swiper-slide-inside ">
        <div class="align-vertical">
            <img src="images/product_images/gallery_images/0690-05-bx_3.jpg" alt="Mobile" data-magnifier-src="images/product_images/popup_images/0690-05-bx_3.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide .img-responsive")[0].addEventListener("error", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    console.log('Image not found.');
    document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide')[0].style.visbility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: your `img` tag doesn't  have `img-responsive` class.

Comment: visbility  should be called visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues

- `img` tag doesn't have the class you are using in your selector
- you are trying to hide first `swiper-slide`, rather than parent `swiper-slide`

**Demo**

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide img")[0].addEventListener("error", myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
    console.log('Image not found.');
    //use document.querySelector('.swiper-slide').style.display = "none" if there is only one such element and discard below line
    event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide" data-index="2" style="width: 145px; margin-right: 10px;">
    <div class="swiper-slide-inside ">
        <div class="align-vertical">
            <img src="images/product_images/gallery_images/0690-05-bx_3.jpg" alt="Mobile" data-magnifier-src="images/product_images/popup_images/0690-05-bx_3.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much gurvinder372!